# MYSQL Queries - combination

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to find the first and last name of the customer who has purchased the most expensive product.

**Schema**

---

**Orders**

- orderID
- ordertypeID
- customerID
- quantity
- purchasedate

**Customers**

- customerID
- state
- postcode
- streetNumber
- streetAddress
- customerLn
- customerFn

**Order_Contents**

- orderID
- productID
- quantity

**Products**

- productID
- productCategory
- productName
- productDescription
- unitPrice
- inStock

How can i write this query?

Comment: Start by identifying how exactly these tables relate to each other and the type of each relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub queries as follows.

```
select 
   Customers.customerFN,
   Customers.customerLN
from
    Customers
    inner join Orders  on Orders.customerID = Customers.customerID
   inner join Order_Contents on Order_Contents.orderID = Orders.orderID 
where
    Order_Contents.productID in
    (select Products.productID from Products where Products.unitPrice = (select max(Products.unitPrice) from Products))
```

Comment: this seems to work although it is not returning the customer who purchased the most expensive item. it is returning the first customer in customers.

Comment: getting unknown column in subquery

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems like it should work as a jumping off point (completely naive approach here)

```
SELECT CustomerFn, CustomerLn FROM Customers c
  LEFT JOIN Orders o on o.customerID = c.customerID
  LEFT JOIN Order_Contents oc on oc.orderID = o.orderID
  LEFT JOIN Products p on p.productID = oc.productID
  WHERE oc.productID IN (
    SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE unitPrice = MAX(unitPrice)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   select c.customerFn, c.customerLn
   from customers c join orders o where o.customerID = c.customerID
   join order_contents l where l.orderId = o.orderId
   join products p where p.productId = l.productId
   order by p.unitPrice desc
   limit 1
```